# Appended URL data only populating 1 of 2 Digital Experience Flow Variables

Tags: visual-workflow, digital-experience

What I'm doing: redirecting clients to a public digital experience page with a public Flow.

The URL contains two fields with associated data - Example: Lead_Id=12345 and Products_Checkbox=Marketing

Issue: When I pre-generate the link and navigate to it, the only variable that is pulling from the URL into the Flow field is the Lead_Id. It will NOT pull the Products_Checkbox information.

What I've done: I have triple checked that I didn't misspell any API names and I have tried restructuring the URL to have the Products_Checkbox by itself, first, or last. It will not append. I have checked in my Digital Experience that I didn't add jQuery to the head markup of the page. I have also tried moving the variables to different fields.

My gut is telling me this is something very simple that I'm overlooking, but I've been starring at this too long and reaching out here in hopes someone with fresh eyes and find it.

Screen shots below. Thank you!

**EDIT:** I have created a new variable for testing, and that works just fine...I'm stumped. I tried changing the name of Products_Checkbox to ProductsCheck, but that didn't work.

[image: Digital Experience Flow Screencap]

[image: Digital Experience Builder Screencap]

[image: Flow Variables Assigned in Flow Screencap]

Answer (score 0):

I created a new variable, exactly the same but changed the name and it seems to work now. Not sure if there was something wrong with the naming structure or the variable itself, but if someone runs into this issue in the future, I will leave it here.

- if a variable is having issues, create a new one.